# How do I use reactive MongoDB in Micronaut?

Tags: mongodb, grails-orm, reactivex, micronaut

I am trying to build a reactive service with MongoDB.

I added this dependency to Micronaut:
`compile "io.micronaut.configuration:mongo-reactive"`

I thought this library would pull in RxGorm, but I am not seeing the classes (ex: RxMongoEntity) in my classpath.

Did I misunderstand how to use this library? Are there any guides or docs for mongo-reactive?

Answer (score 0):

The `mongo-reactive` configuration dependency that you've included brings in the [MongoDB Reactive Driver](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#mongoSupport)  It includes support for the Native MongoDB Driver and a non-blocking Reactive Streams MongoClient is available for use.  It is thinner and does not bring in `rx-mongodb` support.

There are a few samples using the reactive-streams `MongoClient` found in the [petstore example](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-examples/tree/master/petstore) in the micronaut-examples repo [within the `PetController` of the `Pets` app](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-examples/blob/master/petstore/pets/src/main/java/example/pets/PetController.java).

If you still wanted RxGORM support for MongoDB I believe you'd have to go with the `mongo-gorm`  (GORM for MongoDB) configuration and sort out how to [setup the MongoDB Rx Drivers to support RxGORM](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/rx/manual/).  I have not had the chance to give it a try so your mileage may vary and let us know what you find!

Comment: hi, is there any sample to updateOne or replace? i need to update document

Comment: @Colin Do you have any updated example or blog with reactive mongo db, those examples are 2 years old, many things might have changed